# How do I configure MySQLi to recognize mysqli commands in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysqli

Currently, I'm trying to test connection to a database from one machine to another. One machine has MySQL installed on it and has a database set up and running, and I want to have another machine connect to it using mysqli in PHP. Both machines are Ubuntu, and I'm using PHP 5.6. I installed the mysql client on the machine I want to use to connect to the database, and when I try and connect to the database in php using the following code:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

    if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL database.";
            exit();
    }
?>
```

it errors out, and shows a "This page isn't working" error page with a HTTP Error 500. I've tried the following:

sudo apt-get install php-mysqli (Got the message that it was installed and at standard version, I assume this is because I installed the mysql client)

phpenmod mysqli (This didn't change anything)

I'm not sure what else I should try. I believe I have PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.1 both installed, will this cause an issue? What steps can you recommend to troubleshoot and fix the issue of mysqli not working?

Comment: Check your server's error.log file. It will give you more info on what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would take a look at the error log on the machine you are trying to connect from. There should be some explanation for the 500 error.

Second, I believe you need to install the mysqlnd PHP extension on the machine you are connection from. The machine that is hosting the database is just doing that. So, you don't need to worry about having PHP install there.

Comment: I checked the error log, I got the error:

    `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in /srv/www/crm/test.php on line 2`

Any ideas on how to make it find the class? And I tried installing the mysqlnd extension, I got the following error:

    `Note, selecting 'php5.6-mysql' instead of 'php5.6-mysqlnd'
    php5.6-mysql is already the newest version.`

Comment: I would uninstall php5.6-mysql and then install php5.6-mysqlnd. mysqli does not exist because of that missing extension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, when I tried to install php5.6-mysqlnd, it automatically installed php5.6-mysql. I did `apt-get purge php5.6-mysql` and then `apt-get install php5.6-mysqlnd`, however during the install, one of the lines was: `Note, selecting 'php5.6-mysql' instead of 'php5.6-mysqlnd'`, unfortunately. Do you know how I can get it to stop automatically installing the mysql version?

Comment: odd. i will do some research on this.

Comment: So interestingly enough, I did a reboot and it worked. I'm not sure where along the way the issue was fixed, but it's resolved now, so that's good. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Accepted this answer because it was helpful in solving the issue, the solution is in the comments.